# SQL Server decimal calculation and default value

Tags: sql-server, decimal

Can someone explain the following results. I have read about the SQL decimal type and the precision and scale amounts when doing multiplication and division, but I still can't understand this:

```
select cast(7 as decimal(25,13))*cast(15 as decimal(25,13)) = 105.0000000000000

select cast(15 as decimal(25,13))/cast(11 as decimal(25,13)) = 1.3636363636363

select cast(7 as decimal(25,13))*cast(15 as decimal(25,13))/cast(11 as decimal(25,13)) = 9.545454

select cast(cast(7 as decimal(25,13))*cast(15 as decimal(25,13)) as decimal(25,13))/cast(11 as decimal(25,13)) = 9.5454545454545
```

So multiplication and division yield 13 decimals, but when chained they suddenly yield 6 decimals. Only when the multiplication is first cast as decimal(25,13) and only then divided, does it again yield 13 decimals. Does SQL Server cast the multiplication into the default decimal(38,0) and then divide this by the decimal(25,13)?

I am working on bom calculations for very low-priced products, and I want all the decimals I can get. Do I need to do this casting on every step or can I somehow set a default for a single query to use this decimal(25,13) on all decimals if not stated otherwise?

Comment: Not sure what you read but [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql) for multiplication and division operators calls out "3. The scale will be set to 6 if it's greater than 6 and if the integral part is greater than 32. In this case, both integral part and scale would be reduced and resulting type is decimal(38,6)."

Comment: @Dan Guzman I believe you should formulate your comment into an answer

Comment: @DanGuzman How does this explain that the multiplication and division by themselves both yield scale 13, but scale 6 when chained? The question is basically that how does adding the extra cast change the calculation as sql server thinks that the multiplication also yields scale 13 (via SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY).

Comment: @DanGuzman Ahh, it's because without the cast the precision is set to 38 and not 25, and this is fixed by the extra cast..

Comment: @mpn275, exactly. Unfortunately, there is no "give me the precision and scale I want" query hint. You'll need to specify the appropriate precision and scale to maximize the resultant scale for your needs.

Comment: @DanGuzman So it is as I feared, thanks anyway. Well, I'm off casting away then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are relevant excerpts from the [precision, scale, and length documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql) for context of decimal multiplication and division behavior.

```
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------------------+
|              Operation               |          Result precision           |   Result scale *    |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------------------+
| e1 * e2                              | p1 + p2 + 1                         | s1 + s2             |
| e1 / e2                              | p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)  | max(6, s1 + p2 + 1) |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------------------+

* The result precision and scale have an absolute maximum of 38. When a result precision is greater than 38, it's reduced to 38, and the corresponding scale is reduced to try to prevent truncating the integral part of a result. In some cases such as multiplication or division, scale factor won't be reduced, to maintain decimal precision, although the overflow error can be raised.

In multiplication and division operations, we need precision - scale places to store the integral part of the result. The scale might be reduced using the following rules:

1. The resulting scale is reduced to min(scale, 38 - (precision-scale)) if the integral part is less than 32, because it can't be greater than 38 - (precision-scale). Result might be rounded in this case.

2. The scale won't be changed if it's less than 6 and if the integral part is greater than 32. In this case, overflow error might be raised if it can't fit into decimal(38, scale)

3. The scale will be set to 6 if it's greater than 6 and if the integral part is greater than 32. In this case, both integral part and scale would be reduced and resulting type is decimal(38,6). Result might be rounded to 6 decimal places or the overflow error will be thrown if the integral part can't fit into 32 digits.
```

Item #3 applies to the third query in your question, which can be observed with `sp_describe_first_result_set`:

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'
select cast(7 as decimal(25,13))*cast(15 as decimal(25,13))/cast(11 as decimal(25,13)) --= 9.545454
';
```

The system_type_name from the above query shows `decimal(38,6)`. Since the expression result scale of 6 is insufficient for your need, an explict `CAST` of the multiplication expression to a decimal type with a lower precision (like you did in the last query in your question) will provide a greater scale for the result type but with an increased risk of overflow.

The explict `CAST` to `decimal(25, 13)` results in a result type of `decimal(38, 13)`:

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'
select cast(
       cast(7 as decimal(25,13))*cast(15 as decimal(25,13)) as decimal(25,13))/cast(11 as decimal(25,13)) --= 9.5454545454545
';
```

Answer (score -1):

I try to do multiplication and then convert to decimal

```
select cast(7*15 as decimal(25,13))/cast(11 as decimal(25,13))
```

Comment: This would not work as the multiplication of 7 and 15 could already be cut down to 6 decimals, as would happen in my case where all database decimal columns have decimal(38,20). The casting after that would only add zeros.